# How to animate the svg rectangle to grow like music wave?

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I have a below code,

```
<div id="akbar">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <g transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-200)">
      <rect x="50" y="0" fill="#f00" width="100" height="100">
        <animate attributeName="height" 
                 from="0" 
                 to="100" 
                 dur="0.5s" 
                 fill="freeze" />
      </rect>
      <rect x="150" y="0" fill="#f70" width="100" height="200">
        <animate 
                 attributeName="height" 
                 from="0" 
                 to="200" 
                 dur="0.5s" 
                 fill="freeze" />
      </rect>
      <rect x="250" y="0" fill="#ec0" width="100" height="150">
        <animate 
                 attributeName="height" 
                 from="0" 
                 to="150" 
                 dur="0.5s" 
                 fill="freeze" />
      </rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I would like to animate the svg rectangle to grow like music waves.

How can I achieve that?

I need [this behavior](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using

- `values`,
- `keyTimes`
- and `keySplines`

attributes of an `<animate>` tag.

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jy1tzaq6/1/).

I stripped your example to single column only:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <g transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-200)">
    <rect x="50" y="0" fill="#f00" width="100" height="100">
      <animate 
        attributeName="height" 
        from="0"
        to="100" 
        dur="1s" 
        fill="freeze"
        values="0; 200; 150; 160; 150; 160"
        keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1"
        keySplines=".42 0 1 1;
                    0 0 .59 1;
                    .42 0 1 1;
                    0 0 .59 1;
                    .42 0 1 1;
                    0 0 .59 1;"
      />
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As it is not perfect yet, you can play around with the attributes to adjust the timing better (`keySplines` especially) and make it more *music waves like*.

As you can see on the provided example, single column steps of movements are:

1. All the way **from bottom to top**
2. Then, **from top to ~83% of height**
3. Then, **from ~83% to ~88%**,
4. Then, **from ~88% to ~83%**,
5. Then, **from ~83% to ~88%**

I guess that increasing the difference between those repeating percentage numbers (83 and 88) will give you slightly better effect than mine (which is based on 75% and 80%, easier to calculate on `widht: 200px`), but it is close.

Also take a look at [CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) on SVG animation, it is very thorough and covers all the details about mentioned attributes - and much more.

Comment: Thanks dude your are resolve my problem and explained very well thanks again... :-)

Comment: hi there is any possible to acheive without using animation element ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339237/how-to-acheive-the-animation-in-path-without-using-css

Comment: Read the article in my answer.